# Creating Apple PEM certificate and RSA private key from .p12 and .cer

Tags: openssl, certificate, rsa, pem

I'm trying to retrieve the certificate and RSA private key from two files I've got:
certificate.cer and key.p12

I tried to get them with these commands:

CERTIFICATE

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.cer -inform der -out certificate.pem
```

RSA

```
openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:123456 | openssl rsa -out key.pem
```

I try to test it like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
-cert certificate.pem -key key.pem
```

And I get this error:

```
140553388308128:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this link, explains everything you need to do step by step. This tutorial was the only way I got my push notifications working:

http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

It explains how push notifications work, and even shows you some php code to send pushes, but I think the Certificates section is what you're looking for.

Good luck!